# Can React-Native's Native side request information from React? (Bridging/Native Modules)

Tags: ios, objective-c, event-handling, react-native, communication

**TLDR**: Is there some way I can use a callback or get a return value from react to my native code (iOS)? Or can I use a set of locks to enforce ordering for eventdispatcher and eventemitter listeners to enforce an ordering?

**More Information:**

So I'm using the event dispatcher in my iOS code (self.bridge.eventDispatcher) and that's working great. I'm able to send events with information to my react code.

However, I noticed that this works asynchronously. I currently use this because if I require information on my iOS side, I send a ping to my react side requesting this information. I then lock upon the request and wait for my react code to use NativeModules and invoke an iOS method where I get the requested data.

Basically, enforcing a synchronous pattern feels a little dangerous because I'm not sure whether bridging methods can fail. For example, I can send an event to react and then lock. If my react side does not get it, or fails to send a notification to the iOS side, then I will never unlock and then will have deadlock. So to this, I have two questions. Is bridging reliable enough to avoid deadlocking through this method? Or is there a better way to accomplish the same result and request information from my react side from my iOS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome so I got it, turns out there's a structure called RCTResponseSenderBlock. I made another

iOS method:

```
-(void)tmpMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback{

  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"channel" body:@{@"Block":callback}

   ] ;

}
```

javascriptReciever:

```
EventEmitter.addListener("channel", async event => {
  console.log(event)
  event.Block(["Hello There"]);
  return;

});
```

ios Method Invocation:

```
[self tmpMethod:^(NSArray* response){
    NSLog((NSString*)[response objectAtIndex:0]); //prints Hello There
  }];
```

**UPDATE**
Turns out when I try to do the same for Android, I can't. The Android platform uses WriteableMap or WriteableArray to send events using the following method:

```
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                           String eventName,
                           @Nullable WritableMap params) {
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
    }
```

WriteableMap and WriteableArray both do not accept objects such as callbacks which made it not possible to request information from the Javascript side. I also attempted to pass in a Promise as opposed to a WriteableMap or WriteableArray and that threw an error. To communicate asynchronously in a synchronous context for android,

> 1. I will have to send an event from native to javascript
> 2. lock twice to prevent further execution in side native
> 3. on my javascript side invoke a method on my native side once viewing the request with the requested data
> 4. unlock within the native method invoked by javascript
> 5. resume execution since the program has been unlocked
> 6. unlock once further after handling whatever needed to be handled synchronously. (Comment if you want my code implementation)

EDIT AGAIN:
The above flow didn't work. I don't have any control over threads in Android since ReactNative always uses the main thread. So if I end up locking the main thread then react-native cannot enter another method to unlock, thus I have deadlock. So not possible to enforce synchronous exchange of data with android.